# I need to flatten a multi dimensional array using JS 's flat method. This is the Array [ ["1", "0"], ["3", "5", ["8", ["10"], "11"] ], ]

Tags: arrays, flatten

```
function flatArrs(arr) {
  let output = arr
    .flat()
    .sort((a, b) => a - b);
  console.log(output);
}

flatArrs([
  ["1", "0"],
  ["3", "5", ["8", ["10"], "11"]],
]);
```

This is the output and all arrays do not show flattened...why? `[ '0', '1', '3', '5', [ '8', [ '10' ], '11' ] ]`

Comment: [`flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) takes a depth parameter which specifies how deep to flatten, the default is `1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) takes a depth parameter which specifies how deep to flatten, the default is 1. To flatten to an arbitrary depth you can pass [`Infinity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity).

MDN details a number of [alternatives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#alternatives), including using `concat()`, recursivity, and generator functions.

```js
function flatArrs(arr) {
  let output = arr
    .flat(Infinity)
    .sort((a, b) => a - b);
  console.log(output);
}

flatArrs([
  ["1", "0"],
  ["3", "5", ["8", ["10"], "11"]],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

[flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) takes a depth parameter which specifies how deep to flatten, the default is 1. In your case it's three level deep. So you need to pass 3 as an argument in order to flatten it.

```js
function flatArrs(arr) {
  let output = arr
    .flat(3)
    .sort((a, b) => a - b);
  console.log(output);
}

flatArrs([
  ["1", "0"],
  ["3", "5", ["8", ["10"], "11"]],
]);
```